# Using CSV columns to Search and Replace in a text file

Tags: python, regex

**Background**

I have a two column CSV file like this:

| Find | Replace |
| --- | --- |
| is | was |
| A | one |
| b | two |

etc.

First column is text to find and second is text to replace.

I have second file with some text like this:

"This is A paragraph in a text file." (Please note the case sensitivity)

**My requirement:**

I want to use that **csv file** to search and replace in the **text file** with three conditions:-

1. whole word replacement.
2. case sensitive replacement.
3. Replace all instances of each entry in CSV

**Script tried:**

```
with open(CSV_file.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    mydict = {(r'\b' + rows[0] + r'\b'): (r'\b' + rows[1]+r'\b') for rows in reader}<--Requires Attention
    print(mydict)

with open('find.txt') as infile, open(r'resul_out.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        for src, target in mydict.items():
            line = re.sub(src, target, line)  <--Requires Attention
            # line = line.replace(src, target)
        outfile.write(line)
```

**Description of script**
I have loaded my csv into a python dictionary and use regex to find whole words.

**Problems**

I used r'\b' to make word boundry in order to make whole word replacement but output gives me "\\b" in the dictionary instead of '\b' ??

using REPLACE function gives like:

"Thwas was one paragraph in a text file."

secondly I don't know how to make replacement **case sensitive in regex** pattern?

If anyone know better solution than this script or can improve the script?

Thanks for help if any..

Comment: Regex is case-sensitive by default. Your solution is already case-sensitive. What makes you think that part is not working? Or did you actually mean case-**in**sensitive?

Comment: Whole word replacement. In regex we need to use \b for word boundary. My dictionary which is uploaded from csv file does not include this. So I have added it manually. But when I add it to each item of dictionary it adds \\b. Double slash not single slash. As a result when I use that dict to replace text it does not replace whole words. I am using pycharm 2020.

Comment: In addition I have used r before \b but it does not take it as literal and \\b is inserted. I think it is taking it as binary representation of string and not the literal \b. How can make it literal \b so that when applied it replaces the whole word.

Comment: I wasn't asking about `\b` and whole word replacement, I was asking about case (in)sensitiveity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more cumbersome approach (more code) but which is easier to read and does not rely on regular expressions. In fact, given the very simple nature of your CSV control file, I wouldn't normally bother using the csv module at all:-

```
import csv

with open('temp.csv', newline='') as c:
    reader = csv.DictReader(c, delimiter=' ')
    D = {}
    for row in reader:
        D[row['Find']] = row['Replace']
    with open('input.txt', newline='') as infile:
        with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            for line in infile:
                tokens = line.split()
                for i, t in enumerate(tokens):
                    if t in D:
                        tokens[i] = D[t]
                outfile.write(' '.join(tokens)+'\n')
```

Comment: Seems to be a solution. I will check shortly and report you back. Thanks

Comment: your reply is very useful regarding usage of CSV DictReader. Thank alot

Answer (score 0):

I'd just put pure strings into `mydict` so it looks like

```py
{'is': 'was', 'A': 'one', ...}
```

and replace this line:

```py
# line = re.sub(src, target, line) # old
line = re.sub(r'\b' + src + r'\b', target, line) # new
```

Note that you don't need `\b` in the replacement pattern. Regarding your other questions,

- regular expressions are case-sensitive by default,
- changing `'\b'` to '\\b' is exactly what the `r''` does. You can omit the `r` and write `'\\b'`, but that quickly gets ugly with more complex regexs.

Comment: I will recheck this solution and reply back shortly Thank you for your kind reply

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I've created a PowerShell script that helps you to replace a string in many files at once.

To use it, you have to create a CSV file with the columns "FindText" (the text to be replaced) and "ReplaceText" (with the string to replace with), and then replace the variable "$CsvFile" in the script with the path to the file. Then, replace the variable "$ScanDirectory" with the directory where the files are (where you need to replace the strings).

This is my PowerShell script:

```
$CsvFile = "C:\Users\garci\Desarrollo\powershell\fks.csv"
$ScanDirectory = "C:\Users\garci\Desarrollo\salesforce\UNICOERP\force-app\main\default\lwc"

$Files = Get-ChildItem $ScanDirectory -Recurse
$totalLines = (Import-Csv $CsvFile).count
$currentLine = 0

# Write-Output $totalLines

Import-Csv $CsvFile | ForEach-Object {
    $currentLine += 1
    $percentComplete = ($currentLine / $totalLines) * 100
    # Write-Output $percentComplete
    Write-Progress -Activity "Replace in progress" -Status "$percentComplete% Complete:" -PercentComplete $percentComplete

    Foreach($File in $Files) {
        $content = Get-Content -Path $File.FullName -Raw
        if($content.Length -gt 0){
            $content = $content.Trim()
            $patron = [regex]::Escape($_.FindText)
            
            if( $content -match "\b$patron\b"){
                [regex]::Replace($content,"\b$patron\b",$_.ReplaceText) | Set-Content $File.FullName
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Save the script with extension "ps1" and run it with PowerShell.

**Note**: if the files are opened by any other application, the script will fail.

**Another note**: the regex function is case sensitive and replaces whole words only.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).